# Why left joins in BigQuery do not filter the right side table on its time partitioned field?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I have two tables in BigQuery, `l` and `r`. 
Both have the same structure:

- `ts` `TIMESTAMP`
- `a` `INTEGER`
- `b` `INTEGER`

Also, both are time partitioned on the `ts` field. The main difference is that `r` has some duplicated rows while `l` has only unique (`a`,  `b`, `ts`) tuples.

Obviously the real use case is more complex, I simplified the data as much as possible.

The following query processes `1.2 GB` of data.

```sql
select l.ts, l.a, l.b
from l
join r using(ts, a, b)
```

If I keep only one week of data, the consumption goes down to `48.5 MB`.

```sql
select l.ts, l.a, l.b
from l
join r using(ts, a, b)
where date(l.ts) between "2020-03-16" and "2020-03-22"
```

However, if I switch to a left join, the consumption goes up to `673.5 MB`.

```sql
select l.ts, l.a, l.b
from l
left join r using(ts, a, b)
where date(l.ts) between "2020-03-16" and "2020-03-22"
```

Tables `l` and `r` respectively contain `530.4 MB` and `652.2 MB`. When filtered on the date range, these numbers go down to `21.3 MB` and `27.1 MB`.

When switching to the left join, the consumption of `673.5 MB` is equal to `21.3 MB` + `652.2 MB` (partition scan of `l` + full scan of `r`).

I don't get why we cannot reduce the amount of data scanned in table `r` when using a left join. Is this expected? In that case, why?

In the real use case, I have to use a left join. A workaround is to use the query below, which consumes `48.5 MB`, as expected.

```sql
select l.ts, l.a, l.b
from (select * from l where ts between "2020-03-16" and "2020-03-22") l
left join (select * from r where ts between "2020-03-16" and "2020-03-22") using(ts, a, b) r
```

However for my use case (use with Tableau) it is far from ideal.

Comment: have you tried to just add following to your WHERE clause - `AND date(r.ts) between "2020-03-16" and "2020-03-22"`? I think this might provide hint to BQ Engine to use respective partitions on right table

Comment: I did try that, it did not change anything.

Comment: Maybe it's because different merging column strategies between `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` , explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Join-Types_132067691).